# How to pull random cells in an Excel row, using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, openpyxl

I am creating this flahscard application, using Python and openpyxl, which allows me to connect an excel document to my application.

The jist of the problem, is that I have a Label widget, which is supposed to show a random question from column A, and then I have another Labed widget, that is supposed to show the answer.

I know I can call a cell using the `ws["A1"]` (for calling cell A1 specifically), but I can't quite figure out how to make it pick a random cell from the column?

And once I have a way to call a random cell in column A, I need to grab the answer from the corresponding cell in column B.

I hope this made some sort of sense

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a random integer between `1` and some number `n`?

Comment: Not quite, I have the two collums, where i just need it to fetch a value, from a random row in collum A, while i also need the corresponding value in collum be. Example: i want a random value from A, it fetches A37, i now have that, so that i can throw it into a label where the question is supposed to go, now i need it to also fetch me the value from B37, so that i can but that into the "answer" label